# Use Cassandra as Job Repository

Tags: cassandra, spring-xd

I've seen JDBC Drivers out there for Cassandra.

Anyone knows if would it be possible to use Cassandra as a Job Repository for Spring XD?

Comment: Officially it's not supported since we don't test it.  That being said, a PR to Spring Batch (where the repo really originates from) would be appreciated to support it.

Comment: Pull Request: https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: Feel free to contact me offline to discuss (DM me on twitter, etc)

Comment: Hi guys!  would like to use Spring Batch to store data to Cassandra through Spring-Data-Cassandra, but I would like also to have possibility to store my job configuration. Unfortunately I'm not able to have both (sql and no-sql) dbs. Sth has changed over last 2 years?